# How to care for calathea plants

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, indoors, urban-gardening, prayer-plants

I have chosen to grow *Calathea* as an indoor plant, but how should I care for them? How should I overcome the problems that occur during their growth?

Answer (score 1):

Every plant has its requirements to grow, so **know before you sow**!
Calathea is a famous choice for gardening because when given the proper care, it revives your surroundings ten folds. The bright, colorful leaves with diverse patterns are the most striking feature of a **[Calathea](https://bountyquestion.com/q/9hd48s2ii2/how-to-plant-grow-and-care-for-calathea)**, making them eye-pleasing and useful for many purposes like food wrapping, as a gift for gardening enthusiasts, and in weaving baskets. Serving as an ornamental plant, Calathea is grown for economic uses.
Symbolizing a "new beginning" or "starting afresh," Calathea is a perfect choice for gardening beginners, as they are relatively easy and hassle-free to grow. But before delving into the deep wonders of gardening, it is essential to understand how to care for a Calathea plant because when grown indoors, it needs adequate conditions and proper Calathea care for them to thrive. Or else, a plethora of problems will ruin those exotic houseplants in no time.
**How to care for Clathea plants? All you need to know!**

**Children, marriages, flower gardens, and houseplants always reflect the care they get in healthy and happy growth.**
Calathea is a tropical plant native to Brazillian rainforests. It makes a great indoor plant and amazes its owner with its mesmerizing feature of "nyctinasty," in which the leaves fold during the night time in a "prayer hand" position, giving them the nickname of a "prayer plant." This striking feature occurs due to the Sun's movement, ensuring Calathea care by maximizing light absorbancy.
Here are a few tips and tricks to keep your Calathea plant healthy:

- The amount of light should be just right. Calathea does not need a
  lot of light due to its light absorbent power. Hence, they grow great
  in shades and partial sunlight.
- To prevent Calathea slaughter, you need to water! You might find this
  houseplant as a bit "diva-ish" when it comes to watering, as regular
  tap water does not suit their growth. They need distilled or filtered
  water, and only once in a week or two.
- Keep a check on humidity and temperature. Calathea plant loves high
  humidity; therefore, if the indoors have low humidity levels,  keep
  misting the plants and leaves now and then. Calathea Care is
  disrupted if the temperature drops below 60 degrees Fahrenheit, thus
  keeping the temperature maintained between 65 and 80 degrees.

When all of the conditions are maintained just right, there is no stopping your Calathea plants.

**Problems a Calathea plant might face, and their solutions on the go!**

Sometimes, even when the care is done just right, a few problems may occur due to human error. **Worry not; focus on the solutions and not the issues.**

- If the leaves start to wilt or curl and the soil seems dry, the
  Calathea plant is under-watered. It would be best if you increased
  the frequency of watering.
- If your eye catches a black base or yellow leaves on the Calathea
  houseplant, you have been over-watering it. Decrease the frequency
  and amount of water.

**Pro-tip to avoid watering problems: The best way to prevent this problem is to check the soil using the "thumb-rule"; insert your finger in the soil half an inch deep, and if it is dry, water it and vice versa!**

- Leaf spots (discolored patches) indicate that a fungus has infested
  your Calathea plant, or it might also occur if you have been using
  the tap water leading to a mineral excess in the plant. Use organic
  fertilizers and distilled water to avoid such disasters.